# Cytoscape.js - selector for edges attached to selected node

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to set the color of all edges that are attached to a selected node, so that each time a user selects a node any edges that the node is either a source or target of will be a different color.  What would the selector look like for this, or is it not possible?

Comment: Your http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just use a selector, because you need a small graph traversal in addition to the initial filter, e.g.: `cy.$('node:selected').neighborhood('edge')`; i.e. for selected nodes get all connected edges

Or `cy.$('node:selected').connectedEdges()`